# writing if, else on date

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I used Codeigniter and Gammu to make the SMS autoreplay feature. The format in SMS is: DAFTAR#NIK#NAME#DATE

With the date format yyyy-mm-dd. I used the date taken from the #DATE text in the if statement.

```
if($tanggal_periksa==$dataku)
```

is true if the date entered has a range of seven days from the current date. example:
now on 2020-07-17. the if statement is true if we use the date 2020-07-17 to 2020-07-23. other than that date then it is worth wrong. but when I use a date in the span of seven days it is still wrong.

```
    {
        $inboxs= $this->db->get_where('inbox', array('Processed'=>'false'));
        foreach ($inboxs->result() as $inbox)
        {
            $pesan= $inbox->TextDecoded;
            $no_hp = $inbox->SenderNumber;
            $pecah = explode("#", $pesan);
            $key=$pecah[0];
            $keyword=trim($key);
            if(strtoupper($keyword)=='DAFTAR')
            {
                if(count($pecah)==4)
                {
                    $NIK=trim($pecah[1]);
                    $nama=$pecah[2];
                    $tanggal_periksa=$pecah[3];// i got it from #DATE
                    $tahun = date('Y');
                    $bulan = date('m');
                    $tanggal = date('d');
                    $format = $tahun.'-'.$bulan.'-'.$tanggal;
                    $seminggu = abs(6*86400);
                    $awal = strtotime($format);
                    $akhir = strtotime($format)+$seminggu;
                    $sub_kalimat = substr($tanggal_periksa,4,1);
                    $sub_kalimat1 = substr($tanggal_periksa,7,1);
                    $jumlah_karakter = strlen($tanggal_periksa);
                    // echo "<br>".$akhir;
                    if($jumlah_karakter==10 && $sub_kalimat=="-" && $sub_kalimat1=="-")//done
                    {
                        for($i=$awal; $i <=$akhir;$i+=86400)
                        {
                            $dataku=date('Y-m-d', $i);
                            if($tanggal_periksa==$dataku)
                            {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a function that you can reuse - example:

```
function checkDateRange($start, $end, $range) {
    /* $start and $end are datestrings in YYYY-MM-DD format */
    /* $range is an integer, representing range in days */

    $range = $range * 24 * 60 * 60;
    $time_start = strtotime($start);
    $time_end = strtotime($end);
    
    return
        /* check if END date if after START date */
        ($time_end - $time_start >= 0)
        &&
        /* check if END date is in RANGE */
        ($time_end - $time_start < $range);
}
```

So, you can call this function whenever you need to check if a date is in range - example:

```
$TODAY = date("Y-m-d"); // "2020-07-17"

checkDateRange($TODAY, "2020-07-16", 7); // returns false
checkDateRange($TODAY, "2020-07-17", 7); // returns TRUE

checkDateRange($TODAY, "2020-07-23", 7); // returns TRUE
checkDateRange($TODAY, "2020-07-24", 7); // returns false
```

Also, you can use [DateTime::diff - PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to create the same function:

```
function checkDateRange($start, $end, $range) {
    
    $date_start = new DateTime($start);
    $date_end = new DateTime($end);
    
    return
        /* check if END date if after START date */
        $date_end->diff($date_start)->invert != 1
        &&
        /* check if END date is in RANGE */
        $date_end->diff($date_start)->days <= $range;
}
```